# Popupbox click outside

Tags: javascript, popup

Hello I have an popupbox and I want when I click outside it to auto close the popup, I have the code to open and to close it by links but I cant close it by clicking on the background or in the body can some1 help me ?

```js
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```css
.popup-position{
  position :fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#popup-wrapper{
  width: 500px;
  transform: translateX(85%) translateY(200%);

}

#popup-container{
  background-color:white;
  padding: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div id="popup-box1" class="popup-position">
      <div id="popup-wrapper">
        <div id="popup-container">
          <h3>PopUp 1 teste contactos</h3>
          <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">Close PopUp</a></p>
          <p
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">Open PopUp</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```css
.popup-position{
  position :fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#popup-wrapper{
  width: 500px;
  transform: translateX(85%) translateY(200%);

}

#popup-container{
  background-color:white;
  padding: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div id="popup-box1" class="popup-position" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">
      <div id="popup-wrapper">
        <div id="popup-container">
          <h3>PopUp 1 teste contactos</h3>
          <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">Close PopUp</a></p>
          <p
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">Open PopUp</a></p>
```

Simply add your toggle handler on the top most parent element and it should work. In your case here `<div id="popup-box1" class="popup-position" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">`